# "vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset" error using `or`

Tags: prometheus

**UPDATE**: It actually works, don't know why I was getting an error (?)

---

So I want to display the average execution time of requests by path:

```
sum by (path) (rate(request_duration_milliseconds_sum[5m])) 
/ 
sum by (path) (rate(request_duration_milliseconds_count[5m]))
```

works, but does not generate valid values in the intervals when there are no requests, resulting in a pretty horrible graph, to fix this I tried:

```
sum by (path) (rate(request_duration_milliseconds_sum[5m])) 
/ 
( sum by (path) (rate(request_duration_milliseconds_count[5m])) > 0 )
or
sum by (path) (rate(request_duration_milliseconds_count[5m])) > bool 0
```

that should not use 0 count values in the division, and then re-introduce them has `0` via the `or . . . .`

. . . but this fails with a `vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` that I do not understand: `or` is between two series with the same exact label (`path`), and `or` should pick up values from the second one only when there is no value.

What am I missing? . . and how do I fix it.. ?